# Reviewing IF conditional code to save CPU cycles

Tags: c, if-statement

I am reviewing the usage of *if* condition in my program, in there, I have lines like the following:

```
if(count > 4) count = 4;
```

Would it be a good idea to write the above *if* conditional statement as the following non-branched one?

```
count = 4*(count> 4) + count*(count<= 4);
```

I also have the following snippet there:

```
for (j=0, i=0; j<NCARD_PER_SUIT && i<CARDS_PER_PLAYER+CARDS_ON_BOARD; ++j) {
    if (card_cfg.hearts & cfg_mask[j]) {
        player_hand[i].card.face = j;
        player_hand[i++].card.suit = HEART;
    }
    if (card_cfg.spades & cfg_mask[j]) {
        player_hand[i].card.face = j;
        player_hand[i++].card.suit = SPADE;
    }
    if (card_cfg.clubs & cfg_mask[j]) {
        player_hand[i].card.face = j;
        player_hand[i++].card.suit = CLUB;
    }
    if (card_cfg.diamonds & cfg_mask[j]) {
        player_hand[i].card.face = j;
        player_hand[i++].card.suit = DIAMOND;
    }
}
```

and wondering if there is good (non-branched) way to write the above, any suggestions?

EDIT: Based on some feedback below, i compared the assembly instructions (using MSVS2015 for Windows 10) and got the following:

```
; 718  :     count = 4*(count> 4) + count*(count<= 4);

xor ebx, ebx
cmp edx, 4
setle   bl
xor ecx, ecx
imul    ebx, edx
cmp edx, 4
mov edx, 4
cmovg   ecx, edx
add ebx, ecx
```

And if revert back to if statement, i get the following, where no jump instruction and total number of instructions 2/3rd compare to the above:

```
; 718  :     if( count >4) count = 4;

mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$6$[ebp]
cmp edx, edi
mov ebx, DWORD PTR _player$GSCopy$1$[ebp]
cmovg   edx, edi
mov edi, DWORD PTR _count$1$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR _count$4$[ebp], edx
```

EDIT #2: Based on the tip from the comments below, i went ahead and created a

```
union 
typedef union {
    struct cfg {
        unsigned short hearts;  
        unsigned short spades;
        unsigned short clubs;
        unsigned short diamonds;
    } suit;
    unsigned long long allsuits;
} card_cfg_t;
```

And with help of this union, i was able to rewrite the second snippet of OP as follows, which seem sot save a lot (20% in my case) if I build it for 64-bit machine and takes more time (extra 40%) if i build it for 32-bit machine:

```
for (j=0, i=0; j<NCARD_PER_SUIT && i<CARDS_PER_PLAYER+CARDS_ON_BOARD; ++j) {
    for (int k=0; k<4; ++k) {
        present = (int)((card_cfg.allsuits & (cfg_mask[j] << 16*k)) != 0);
        player_hand[i].card.face = j*present;
        player_hand[i].card.suit = k;
        i = i + present;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sure. Thanks for suggestion, I will post it there.

Comment: Are you certain that `count = 4*(count> 4) + count*(count<= 4);` does not result in branches to handle the `count> 4` and `count<= 4`?

Comment: I am not certain, that is why this question, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You don't have to wonder; you can just check the assembly that results from that expression.

Comment: @mustaccio This doesn't seem like it should belong in code review, since the person who asked the question already wrote the code for both examples and is merely asking which one is faster.

Comment: As far as whether it would be "better" (assuming it doesn't require branching to handle the `>` and `<=` conditions), that may depend on the architecture. On architectures where multiplies are expensive (e.g. some embedded platforms), the branched implementation would likely be faster.

Comment: I agree with @Cppplus1 that this seems perfectly on topic here, and better suited for this site than for [codereview.SE]. People there expect to be able to offer general feedback on any aspect of the code, not just performance.

Comment: `count = 4*(count> 4) + count*(count<= 4);` --> Maybe save a cycle, earn low review marks.  `if(count > 4) count = 4;` Oh happy day! - focus on significant time issues.

Comment: See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-minimum-or-maximum-max-of-two-integers-without-branching/ although I'm sure this is not where any performance bottleneck lies, so best keep things readable.

Comment: You should test if this does really result in a performance improvement. It doesn't look as is this a bottleneck. If there is any improvement or not also depends on the target system.

Comment: What about, in general, impact of a missed branch prediction in case of if statement in this case? Would not that cause branched instructions perform worse?

Comment: Please also note the EDIT to the OP above.

Comment: I doubt that the assembly snippets you added fully implement the logic of the indicated C statements, at least not the 2nd one. Those assembly lines may be PART of the logic, but not all of it. To make it easier to see, implement the lines as separate simple functions, and examine the assembly of each entire function. That won't necessarily result in an instruction sequence that's identical to what you would see with the inline statements, but it would give you a better idea of the full scope of the assembly required for each.

Comment: BTW, you may have to place those functions in separate compilation units (.c files), or else disable inlining in the compiler options, otherwise the compiler may just inline those super-simple functions, defeating your purpose.

Comment: On the second part of the question: The order of iteration looks backward to me. I'm guessing that you will get better improvements by rethinking the algorithm than by optimizing for assembly generation.  You could add some more context and make that a separate question - maybe for codereview.soe

Comment: If 64bit ints are available, you can avoid (most of) the loops by storing all 52 cards in a single 64 bits bitmask. (or a mask per player + one for the table or dealer)

Comment: @joop i m trying to stay compatible with 32-bit

Comment: @joop - That is an awesome idea. Vikas, consider that... it may mean a good bit of rework, but it could eliminate a ton of loops. As far as staying compatible with 32-bit goes, even most 32-bit platforms support `uint64_t`; the compiler manufactures it from two adjacent 32-bit integers and as far as your program logic is concerned, it's no different from a 64-bit integer on a 64-bit platform. The cards of each suit can be represented by 13 bits each, with (if applicable) extra bits representing jokers. Or if you'd rather, use `uint16_t`'s, one for each suit. Better yet, make a union....

Comment: `typedef union { uint16_t suit[4]; uint64_t allCards; };` and maybe you could refer to either all cards of a given suit, or all cards of the deck all at once, whichever seems best for a given situation.

Comment: Thanks @phonetagger and joop, i was able to use this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those micro optimistion do not have too much sense but of you want to compare (you will see the difference between your one and mine - switch on optimisation - compiler is really good in it):

```
int count;

 void foo()
 {
       count = 4*(count> 4) + count*(count <= 4);
 }

 void foo1()
 {
       count = count > 4 ? 4 : count;
 }

  void foo4()
 {
       if(count> 4) count = 4;
 }

foo:
  mov edx, DWORD PTR count[rip]
  xor ecx, ecx
  cmp edx, 4
  setle al
  setg cl
  movzx eax, al
  imul eax, edx
  lea eax, [rax+rcx*4]
  mov DWORD PTR count[rip], eax
  ret
foo1:
  cmp DWORD PTR count[rip], 4
  mov eax, 4
  cmovle eax, DWORD PTR count[rip]
  mov DWORD PTR count[rip], eax
  ret
foo4:
  cmp DWORD PTR count[rip], 4
  jle .L6
  mov DWORD PTR count[rip], 4
.L6:
  rep ret
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterJ_01 for illustration. Surprising to me, foo1 has no jump instruction, so apparently ternary operator is not implemented like if-then-else! So, is it correct to say that foo1 is the best way to go here?

Comment: Ternary operation is a short hand notation for if/then/else with count being explicitly assigned a value on all branches. It is no silver bullet that removes jumps, even when one lucky compiler generated different code with it. Better use function min and when desperate, tune that based on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second loop must be something like:

```
     pushcards(player, popcards(dealer));
```